# Angular-Formly Nested Model Not Updating

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I am having an interesting issue with angular-formly. I am attempting to use the 'model' tag as shown below because my model is not flat.

```
{
    'key': 'last',
    'model': 'model.name',
    'templateOptions: {}
}
```

However, I cannot update the model in a clean manner. Simply replacing model or even model.name with a matching model that contains the updated value does not cause the model to update the view.

```
var newModel = {
    name: {
        first: 'Gandalf',
        last: 'The White'
    }
};
self.model = {
    name: {
        first: 'Gandalf',
        last: 'The Grey'
    }
};
function setNewLastName() {
    self.model = newModel;
}
setNewLastName();
```

However if I drill down to the specific property, it works as expected.

```
self.model.name.last = self.newModel.name.last;
```

Here is a link to a JSBin where the value updates using the drill-down method immediately above.
[Drill-down JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jewapi/edit?js,console,output)

Another JSBin that attempts to update the model by assigning a new model that does not update.
[Assign Model JSBin](http://jsbin.com/newuri/edit?js,console,output)

Has anyone ran into this issue or can you see where I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You replace the model for each key, therefore you never see the changes.

What you need to do is to **match the model in the key itself**.

```
vm.fields = [
  {
    key: 'name.first', // <-- HERE
    type: 'input',
    //model: vm.model.name, //Wrong
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'First Name'
    }
  },
  {
    key: 'name.first', // <-- AND HERE
    type: 'input',
    //model: vm.model.name, //Wrong
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Last Name'
    }
  },
  //...
];
```

See corrected example: http://jsbin.com/pupijoc/1/edit?js,console,output

---

**UPDATE**: Nested properties are also handled by [fieldGroups](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/field-groups)

Se updated example: http://jsbin.com/pupijoc/3/edit?js,console,output

Comment: That works but it doesn't solve the issue that the model attribute is intended to solve. Now you have to create a different template for every n number of nested properties or implement a switch or hide show.

Comment: Nested properties are better achieved by using fieldGroups, let me update the example

Comment: That works as well, but it is still a hack/workaround really. Per the formly documentation what I am doing is the intended use case of 'model'. It is also very unclean to have n layers of fieldGroups wrapping your fields where some may be two deep and others five.

Comment: I don't understand why would you need to specify the model for each field. Anyway I tried removing the directive's binding in the HTML: http://jsbin.com/gafinic/2/edit?js,console,output , maybe you want to raise the issue in our gitter channel: gitter.im/formly-js/angular-formly

Comment: Here's another example using model as a formlyExpression:http://jsbin.com/gafinic/edit?js,console,output
This might be a bug, or maybe a watcher is needed: http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formly-expressions#watcher

Comment: It's been in the gitter and I created an issue as well. The APIs that I'm using are what's causing the issues with the model. I could flatten it and map it later but that's a lot of overhead in this case. I assumed it was missing a watcher as well as the model updates, the value just isn't passed to the screen. If you don't mind point me to the right section in the source code and I'll try to get it to pull request status.

Comment: Thank you for the help as well.